# How to show color value in the google geo chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, google-visualization

I want to display the google geo chart like this.

[image]

I got the world map, but i didn't get the value for each color

[image]

I have searched lot and read the google visualization documentation also. Nothing i got. If anyone know about this please help.

Comment: `i didn't get the value for each color` get from who? Are you want that google will provide you the color?

Comment: If google visualization has function for that means i want that. I didn't see any function like that. So any other alternative for that to get the value that indicated by each color? and thanks for the comment

Comment: Can you post a fiddle (update your question) with your example and more specific details. Like: "I want to get the color of specific country when I click on it"

Comment: @Sivabalan did you complete this?

Comment: No i didn't get that still

Answer (score 0):

The colors are fixed with the values, you can do it with static markup and style.

For example:

```css
.block-geomap {
  position: relative;
}

.block-color {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .7);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.color-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.color-item span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.color-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.color-green {
  background-color: green;
}

.color-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-geomap">
  <div class="block-color">
    <ul class="color-list">
      <li class="color-item"><span class="color-blue"></span>0-5%</li>
      <li class="color-item"><span class="color-green"></span>5%-10%</li>
      ...
      <li class="color-item"><span class="color-red"></span>>35%</li>
      <li class="color-item"><span class="color-white"></span>No Data</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E7z6.png"/ alt="GEO map">
</div>
```

Comment: That colors will be dynamic